# Why is container div not wrapping the child divs (which are overflowing the container)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a title and description in a out div that will wrap them. I have `<div class="category_border">` wrapped around the title and description, but for some reason they are falling out of it. I have created a fiddle to help show what it is doing. Why aren't they falling in `<div class="category_border">`?

https://jsfiddle.net/0vkzoxm3/

Comment: I edited the title of your post to improve searchability and clarify your intent. If there's a misinterpretation please comment or update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` to the `.category_border` class.

Here's your updated demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/0vkzoxm3/3/

The reason your title and description overflow the containing `div` is because both are styled with `float: left`. When you float an element it is taken out of the normal flow. Hence, as far as the container `div` is concerned they don't exist.

The answer is to "clear" the floats. There are many ways to do this. One way is to add `overflow: auto` to the container. This forces the container to expand to the height of the floated elements.

Here's a bit more if you're interested:

[Clearing Floats: An Overview of Different clearfix Methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

[How Floats are Positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#How_floats_are_positioned)

Good luck!

Comment: I need those grids in there for other positioning I will need to add.

Comment: Ok. I adjusted my answer.