# CSS3 misunderstanding of overflow property

Tags: html, css

I always thought that changing the `overflow` property of an element's style would only decide what to do with content outside an element's boundaries, not decide whether children are inside or outside.

I have this code:

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container .left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#container .right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>container text</h1>
  <div class="left">
    <h2>left text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>right text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I change `overflow` from `hidden` to `visible`, the `.left` and `.right` child elements appear to be outside of their parent box which is in contrast to when the `overflow` property is set to `hidden`. Why is the `overflow` property behaving in this way?

Comment: I just answered a nearly identical question. It may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622484/why-is-container-div-not-wrapping-the-child-divs-which-are-overflowing-the-cont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using `float`s, therefore you need to clear the `float`s

more about [clearing floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Clearing_floats) and [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Snippet with(`overflow:visible`):

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; 
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

#container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: visible;
}
#container .left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#container .right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cf">
  <h1>container text</h1>
  <div class="left">
    <h2>left text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>right text</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

In this snippet I used a [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)